# Calculate contour integral

Tags: contour-integration

> Calculate $\displaystyle \int_\Gamma \frac 1{z^4 + 81}$ where $\Gamma:
>  |z+i| = \frac 34$

Can somebody help me with this question please or give me a hint on how to get started, as I have never seen a question with gamma like this and I have no idea how to start.

Thanks

Comment: Gamma is just the region of integration, dont worry about that.

Comment: I still do not understand this question, can someone please explain in more detail? thank you

Comment: Please tell me where you cant understand the problem....

Comment: i think i understand now, none of the roots are in the contour, so is the answer 0?

Comment: yes...If the roots are not in or within the contour, then its 0

Answer (score 3):

Solve for $z^4 = -81$, you will get four roots and write it as $\frac{1}{z^4 + 81}=\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)}$ where a,b,c,d are roots of the above $z^4 = -81$. Then use partial fractions $\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)} = \frac{A}{z-a}+\frac{B}{z-b}+\frac{C}{z-c}+\frac{D}{z-d}$. Find the value of A,B,C,D and then substitute in the above equation and then integrate using Cauchys integral formula.

Comment: What do you need partial fractions for? You just need to calculate the residue :-)

Comment: are the roots  3/√(2) + [3/√(2)]i,  -3/√(2) + [3/√(2)]i,  -3/√(2) - [3/√(2)]i, 3/√(2) - [3/√(2)]i ?

Comment: I do not understand how to do partial fractions with this question

Comment: and none of the roots are in gamma are they? i'm confused...